# A subset of $Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and the $|H|$ is the smallest prime that divides $|G|$, then $H \subset Z(G)$.

First I note that (1) $|G/C_G(H)|$ divides the $|Aut(H)|$, how can i  prove this using this (1)?

Comment: Repeat; you can find my answer to this question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227971/g-group-h-trianglelefteq-g-vert-h-vert-prime-prove-h-leq-zg/227973#227973

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $H$ is cyclic of prime order, this makes it possible to determine the size of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$.
The rest follows from Lagrange's Theorem and the hypothesis on $|H|$.

Comment: Since $p$ is a prime, $H$ is cyclic. So $|\text{Aut}(H)| = \varphi(p) = p-1 $. So by Lagrange's theorem $|N_G(H)|/ |C_G(H)|$ divides $p-1 $. Since $N_G(H) = G$, $\frac{|G|}{C_G(H)}$ divides $p-1$. Since $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $G$, we must have $|C_G(H)| = |G|$.So $G = C_G(H)$. This is same as saying $H \le Z(G)$.

Comment: @Knight: That is mostly right, I will criticize one thing though. It is by your statement (1) and not by Lagrange's theorem that $|G|/|C_G(H)|$ divides $p-1$. You *then* use Lagrange's Theorem to verify a divisor of $p-1$ divides $|G|$.